# Selecting drop box (VBA)

Tags: vba, selenium-chromedriver

I can click drop box option with my code.
But i want to click this based on value on excel sheets.

What should i do to do it? I made sheet1 and there is option 1 (text) in A2 cell.

```
Sub Dropdowncombobox()

Dim bot As New WebDriver


bot.Start "chrome"

bot.Get "https://the-internet.herokuapp.com/dropdown"

Stop

Dim ele As SelectElement
Set ele = bot.FindElementById("dropdown").AsSelect

ele.SelectByText "Option 1"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the value of the cell and pass it further as follows:

```
ele.SelectByText Sheet1.Range("A2").Value
```